# GUI for adding Fedora software source

Tags: fedora, install, rpm, yum

Is there a GUI for adding additional software sources in Fedora (FC 13).  I have a software repository that works fine when added manually (as a .repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d/), but I'd like to have a better way of telling end users how to install.

Comment: +1 Ahh, the classic problem of people not being able to use a text editor on a file.

Comment: They don't even need that (they can copy a prewritten .repo file).  But for a consumer application, I think it's reasonable for things named `/etc/a.b.c` to be off-putting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PackageKit, the default package management tool in Fedora 13, does not include a method and it's unlikely that they ever will as it's a [deliberate design choice to not include repository management](http://www.packagekit.org/pk-faq.html#repo-add-remove).

However, could you instead package up the repo file into an RPM and distribute that? By default RPMs will open with Package Installer and that's GUI based.

Comment: We can (and do), but when we distribute a set of RPMs (multiple apps with common dependencies) it's sad to make the user figure out the right install order.  I'll look into the repo-release.rpm model.